# Invoke repeatable task when viewDidApper

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, infinite-loop

I might be heading totally wrong direction, but what I'm trying to achieve is to load some view first and invoke some methods that will be running afterwards infinitely, while at the same time giving the User the possibility to interact with this view.

My first guess was to use viewDidApper with UIView.animate, as per below;

```
class MainView: UIView {
        ...
        func animateTheme() {
            //want this to print out infinitely
            print("Test")
        }    
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBOutlet weak var mainView: MainView!        

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .repeat, animations: {
            self.mainView.animateTheme()
        }, completion: nil)    
    }
}
```

The case is that I can only see a single "Test" printed out but this has to be invoked infinitely. Also, as I mentioned the User needs to have the possibility to interact with the view once everything is loaded.

Thanks a lot for any of your help.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewDidAppear` will indeed be called latest when the view is loaded, but I don´t think the user can or will have the time to interact before it´s loaded.

If you want to load animations after everything is loaded you could create a timer and wait x seconds before you do that. Below example will be called 10 seconds after initiation.

```
var timer = Timer()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(animateSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func animateSomething() {
    // Animate here
}
```

**Update**
To make an infinite loop you can use the following snippet:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for the reply. I should have been more specific on the case. What I want to achieve is a situation when everything is loaded so the User can start interact and there is a process running in the background (in an infinite way), for instance some visible object constantly changes it's color.

Comment: So you want to do an infinite animation @RafalK?

Comment: that's exactly what I need :)

Comment: @RafalK, check the update, you just have to change the parameters and what you need to animate, but that should help you get started.

Comment: I started with something very similar - changed the post to reflect where I was at the very beginning. The case is that I can only see "Test" string being printed once. I can't achieve infinite loop this way...

Comment: @RafalK, If my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you"ve been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar on one of my ViewControllers that loads a `UIWebView`. While the webpage is loading I show a `UILabel` with text "Loading" and every 1.5 seconds I add a period to the end of the text. I think the approach you describe above and mine shown below have the same effect and neither would be considered an infinite loop.

```
private func showLoadingMessage(){
    let label = loadingLabel ?? UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
    label.text = "Loading"

    view.addSubview(label)
    loadingLabel = label
    addEllipsis()
}

private func addEllipsis() {

    if webpageHasLoaded { return }
    guard let labelText = loadingLabel?.text else {
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
        self.loadingLabel?.text = labelText + "."
        self.addEllipsis()
    }
}
```